# Properly Refresh data from Database JPA - Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-4.x

I'm currently using the JPA specs to query my objects from the database.

Everytime there's a change made by me (my instance of the software), the items would be properly refreshed.

But, if there's another change made by someone else (other instance, or database change), the items are'nt being properly refreshed.

I'm using a simple "find" with "refresh"

```
Object found = getManager().find(getModelClass(), id);
getManager().refresh(found);
```

I'm using a DAO Hierarchy, the "getModelClass" returns my @Entity class like

```
@Override
protected Class<?> getModelClass() {
    return ProductCategory.class;
}
```

And my Manifest / persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<persistence xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence">
    <persistence-unit name="casa" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
       <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>

        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />

            <!-- localhost -->
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="root" />


            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="false" />
            <property name="hibernate.use_sql_comments" value="false" />
            <property name="hibernate.jdbc.wrap_result_sets" value="false" />
            <property name="hibernate.hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" /> 

        </properties>

    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Also each "DAO" have and instance of and EntityManager of it's own.

What I might be doing wrong ?

Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like my problem was simple.

The refresh transaction to be properly refreshed from the database needs to be commited

```
getManager().getTransaction().begin();
T found = (T) getManager().find(getModelClass(), id);
getManager().refresh(found);
getManager().getTransaction().commit();
```